# Dense subsets of an arbitrary set $X$.

Tags: general-topology

I know a subset $Y$ of a topological space $X$ is dense iff $\overline Y = X$ where $\overline Y$ is the closure.

If we have $\mathbb{R}$ as our topology $X$, then we know $\mathbb{Q}$ is a dense subset $Y$. Similarly, the real numbers less one element and the rational numbers less one element are both dense subsets $Y$.

This is because every arbitrarily chosen point of $Y$ either belongs to $X$ or else is "close" to a random member of $X$.

If $X$ is an arbitrary set *with the cofinite topology.* I have been told that a dense subset of such an $X$ is a subset $Y$ whose complement in $X$ is a finite set.

Without knowing (roughly) how large $X$ and $Y$ are, how can we know which subsets of $X$ are dense using the closure? I'm thinking of the closure as the intersection of all closed sets in $X$ containing $Y$. It seems like denseness of a subset could only be true if the subset was $X$ less some deliberately small number of elements, specifically chosen.

Comment: That totally depends on $X$. Some topological spaces can have a single point dense while they themself are arbitrarily large.

Comment: That's good to know. I agree that it seems highly situational. If it was $\mathbb{R}$ with the cofinite topology, you could intuit that the dense subsets coincide with the infinite subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: I meant we have $X$ with the cofinite topology where $X$ is not specifically given as $\{a,b,c\}$ or some such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will assume that $X$ is an infinite set.

If $Y$ is finite, the $Y$ is closed, and therefore $\overline Y=Y$.

And if $Y$ is infinite, then $\overline Y\supset Y$ and therefore $\overline Y$ is infinite too. So, since it is closed, $\overline Y=X$.

The conclusion is that $Y$ is dense if and only if it is an infinite subset of $X$.

Comment: I had contemplated this for $\mathbb{R}$ with the cofinite topology, but wasn't certain if it held true for every infinite $X$ with the cofinite topology. Thank you.